# seaborn plots the same size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, seaborn

seaborn has a conveninent keyword named `size=`, that aims to make the plots a certain size. However, the plots significantly differ in size depending on the xy-ticks and the axis labels. What is the best way to generate plots with exactly the same dimensions regardless of ticks and axis labels?

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn sizing options vary by the plot type, which can be a bit confusing, so this is a useful universal approach.

First run this: `import matplotlib as plt`

Then add the line `plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))` in the notebook cells for each of the plots. You can adjust the integer values as you see fit.

Comment: In that case the box of the plot will have different sizes depending on the x/y labels and ticks.